How to remove proxyaddresses from B2C user?
I'm trying to update a user's email, but I can't because the proxy addresses are already in use. The problem is that the email is a proxy address of another, not the main one, and we cannot use it for another user. Is there a way to remove the proxy addresses without removing the user?


As mentioned in this MS Doc,

For Azure AD B2C accounts, proxyAddresses property has a limit of 10 unique addresses. Read-only in Microsoft Graph; You can update this property only through the Microsoft 365 admin center. Cannot be updated to null.

When I tried to remove proxy addresses by running below PATCH request for Azure AD B2C user in Microsoft Graph Explorer, I too got same error:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userID/
{
    "proxyAddresses": []
}

Response:

If users are licensed, you can only update or remove proxyAddresses via below Admin portals:
Microsoft 365 admin center:

Exchange Admin Center:

If users are non-EXO licensed, you can make use of /beta Graph API endpoint to update proxy addresses:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userID/
{
    "proxyAddresses": []
}

Response:

References:
Remove old proxyaddress entry for user in azure active directory b2c - Stack Overflow by floyd
Remove ProxyAddresses from Azure B2C account via powershell (reddit.com) by icebreaker374

Beta patch worked for me, thanks!!

@Pedro Glad to know it worked :)

You might be able to do this via Graph API.
To do this kind of thing, I normally use this utility, adapted from a Microsoft sample.
Update
Using the utility and dumping out the attributes shows:
...
"postalCode": null,
"preferredDataLocation": null,
"preferredLanguage": null,
**"proxyAddresses": [],**
"refreshTokensValidFromDateTime": "2022-01-24T01:45:30Z",
"showInAddressList": null,
"signInSessionsValidFromDateTime": "2022-01-24T01:45:30Z",

That utility allows you to update single attributes.

I do user operations with Graph API, but i dont know exactly with wich one i can remove only ProxyAdresses.

I got this message when I try to update this property: "Property 'proxyAddresses' is read-only and cannot be set."
